# Date hour minute to Date Time in Google Sheets

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a format like this in my Google Sheet:

`14/11/2019 14:39`

I already try to create a new format in Google sheet but it didn't work.

I can change the Format to `14/11/2019 14:39:00` by using this method

```
// data in cell `A2`
=DATE(MID(A2,7,4),MID(A2,4,2),MID(A2,1,2))+TIME(MID(A2,12,2),MID(A2,15,2),"00")
```

So, how do I convert this to DateTime in a simpler way?

Comment: What datetime format do you want? and from exist datetime value or current datetime?

Comment: @HieuNguyenVan edited, thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

As you realize most software does not like day month year format and you pretty much solved the problem for your particular case, the best you can do is put it all in one arrayformula so you do not have to drag it down.

```
={"DateFormat";arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",DATE(MID(A2:A,7,4),MID(A2:A,4,2),MID(A2:A,1,2))+TIME(MID(A2:A,12,2),MID(A2:A,15,2),"00") ))}
```

If you are using this date format you probably live in a country that uses that format so why don't you just change the locale in your Google Sheet or if you are working with a Google Sheet for a different country why not just set the locale to the correct country? Note: after changing the locale you still need to paste in the new dates again because it thought it was the old locale.

Answer (score 0):

you can format it with `TEXT` fx:

```
=TEXT(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m5gSZnngyl3EG692edpP5cwHrhCy3yHEJmB920pSehQ/copy)

---

ArrayFormula variant:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A1:A20, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: I try this, but still return `14/11/2019 14:39`

Comment: @XenonDrey can you share a copy of your sheet?